# Phusion Passenger status crashing with too long socket name

Tags: passenger

I am trying passenger on Ubuntu 18.04, pretty much generic install and the passenger-status call crashes. Not super clear how to set the path that it uses for local socket communication.

```
Version : 6.0.12
Date    : 2021-11-17 23:20:19 +0000
Instance: PdoRpeL5 (Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/6.0.12)

Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:349:in `<main>'
    5: from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:346:in `start'
    4: from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:62:in `command_show_status'
    3: from /usr/sbin/passenger-status:124:in `show_status'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance.rb:94:in `http_request'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance.rb:94:in `new'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/admin_tools/instance.rb:94:in `initialize': too long unix socket path (116bytes given but 108bytes max) (ArgumentError)
```

Looking at that code, `@path` is `/tmp/systemd-private-af50a27a57d04fec9366f72dd251a3be-apache2.service-Dy9bBV/tmp/passenger.PPuC2RN` which makes the socket name `/tmp/systemd-private-af50a27a57d04fec9366f72dd251a3be-apache2.service-Dy9bBV/tmp/passenger.PPuC2RN/agents.s/core_api`

Seems like a passenger internal issue but I'm looking for a workaround...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried editing your web server service file, nginx.service or apache2.service? I had this problem and solved it by removing the line:

```
PrivateTmp=true
```

from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service`.

Then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2397

"this is because the path generated by the systemd private tmp feature is 80 chars long, which only leaves 27 chars for an application to use, and passenger uses 35 chars in its path to its socket."

Comment: I saw elsewhere to change PrivateTmp to false. That worked for me.

Comment: Well yes, that comes to the same thing.